# function template not supported in DLL?

Tags: c++, templates, dll, header

I try to add function templates in my DLL file to make works easier, but failed to do so so far, even if I try to put function templates in the DLL header, it still fail to work, the compiler always give me the annoying unresolved external symbol error (visual studio) whenever I try to use the DLL in other program.

Is there anyway to use function template in DLL(I know I can simply put all function templates in a standalone header file instead of DLL, but that will make the program maintainence a mess).

What I want to do in the DLL is like:

```
    template<typename T>int foo(T*x){...};
```

then call it like:

```
    fooINT(int* x){ return foo<int>(x);};
```

The DLL can be compiled, but it will always give me the error:

unresolved external symbol for __declspec(dllimport)

Whenever visual studio compiled with programs that calling this DLL.

Comment: Without seeing (a) the code, and (b) the error, you ay be waiting awhile. That said, keep all template code out of your .cpp files. And my all of it I mean **all** of it unless it is a template local to the one file it is *declared* **and** *used* in.

Comment: Templates are a compile-time thing, so putting them in any kind of compiled library makes no sense unless they are only used exclusively within the library.

Comment: They may make no sense, but if the compiler can handle templates in DLLs, it sure will be very useful.

Comment: Unless you fully specialise your templates in your DLL interface, you will get linker problems. That's just the way templates work.

Comment: @60080 Useful or not you cannot put template code in a DLL, unless you explicitly instantiate the types you require.